# How can I rise the speed of implementing photo filters?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, cifilter

I have an app where on select UICollectionViewCell with some filter it implements that filter to my UIImage. But it applies this so slowly and with freezes. How can I rise the speed of implementing image filters on my images?

```
func applyFilter(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube")
    filter!.setValue(colorCubeData, forKey: "inputCubeData")
    filter!.setValue(kDimension, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")

    let sourceImage = CIImage(image: image)

    filter.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: filter.outputImage!.extent)

    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: self.imageView.image!.imageOrientation)

    return newImage
}
```

that's my filter code. And I call that in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("filterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FiltersCollectionViewCell

    let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                cell.imageView.image = self.applyFilter(image: self.croppedImage!)
        })
    }

    self.queue!.addOperation(op1);

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You could let it execute in background and show a loading bar until it's ready?

Comment: Did you try downscaling the image? I would run Time Profiler to find the most intensive code you need to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `CIContext` is an expensive operation - you should create it once at reuse it.

You may also want to investigate a GPU render target such as [`GLKView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/) which will speed things up.